# Load and run test a .trt model

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson

I need to run my model in NVIDIA JETSON T2, So I converted my working yoloV3 model into tensorRT(.trt format)(**https://towardsdatascience.com/have-you-optimized-your-deep-learning-model-before-deployment-cdc3aa7f413d**)This link mentioned helped me to convert the Yolo model into .trt .But after converting the model to .trt model I needed to test if it works fine (i.e) If the detection is good enough. I couldn't find any sample code for loading and testing .trt model. If anybody can help me , please pull up a sample code in the answer section or any link for reference.

Comment: Please share your tensorrt version.

Comment: Tensorrt 5.0 ......

Comment: Officiel nvidia tutorial for inference in python using `.trt`: https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/main/quickstart/SemanticSegmentation/tutorial-runtime.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

You can load and perform the inference of your **TRT Model** using this snippet of code.
This is executed in **Tensorflow 2.1.0** and **Google Colab** Environment.

```
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(output_saved_model_dir, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
signature_keys = list(saved_model_loaded.signatures.keys())
print(signature_keys) # Outputs : ['serving_default']

graph_func = saved_model_loaded.signatures[signature_keys[0]]
graph_func(x_test) # Use this to perform inference
```

`output_saved_model_dir` is the location of your **TensorRT Optimized model** in **SavedModel** format.

From here, you can add your **testing** methods to determine the performance of your **pre** and **post-processed** model.

**EDIT:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
import numpy as np 

conversion_params = trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS
conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(max_workspace_size_bytes=(1<<32))
conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(precision_mode="FP16")
conversion_params = conversion_params._replace(maximum_cached_engines=100)

converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(
    input_saved_model_dir=input_saved_model_dir,
    conversion_params=conversion_params)

converter.convert()

converter.save(output_saved_model_dir)
```

Here are the codes used for **Converting** and **Saving** the **Tensorflow RT Optimized** model.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But does tf.saved_model load .trt engine ?

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, Yes. the TRT Engine as you mentioned is saved along with the normal nodes in the SavedModel file. As you can see the code snippet, the way that it is used for inference is different to the normal ```predict(x_test)```, this already uses the signatures saved with the model.

Comment: So In case im using it for object recogination. Is it okay to write a detection script with tensorflow and load this .trt model ?

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, you really need to write it first using Tensorflow, then convert/optimize it using Tensorflow RT. This approach applies to all not only for Object recognition.

Comment: I dint ask about the weight file.

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, in Tensorflow 2 you can only use the SavedModel format for inference, because converting the frozen graphs are not supported in TF2.0. I have editted my answer.

Comment: Thanks,  But I have managed to convert it to onnx then to tensorrt (.trt format ) as I'm using YoloV3 which was originally written in C++. As of now, I have a optimizied .trt model. So, Why does the trt.TrtGraphConverterV2 is called again ?

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, this is all based on NVIDIA's documentation about Tensorflow TensorRT. trt.TrtGraphConverterV2 is used to convert the graph of the model, resulting into a optimized one. ```V2``` means that it is for Tensorflow 2. Also I am discussing here based on Python language as discussed in the documentation in this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html).

Comment: Yeah , As you said it converts Tensorflow model to an optimized Tensorrt model. But that isn't required for me as I have already converted it into Tensorrt through onnx. So, my question was why should I use trt.TrtGraphConverterV2 again

Comment: Hi @SaiKrishnadas, I only included the TrtGraphConverterV2 to show how I created and converted the optimized model. The only thing you need to load your converted model is the first code I included. Then after that you can do anything you want on the model and the rest of the codes.

Comment: Okay, Thanks... I will close this question once I work with them

Comment: Sure thing @SaiKrishnadas, Glad to help. Thanks.